# How can I stop Chrome (re)creating this file on my desktop on every boot

Tags: gnome, chrome, desktop, .desktop

Since installing Chrome on my system (POP!_OS 22.04), every time I log in I am greeted by this annoying file which has placed itself on my desktop. If I delete it, it simply recreates itself again.

I'm not even sure what it is; I assume session or profile data of some sort, although deleting it doesn't seem to make any difference.

In any case, I don't want it there and don't want to see it cluttering my clean workspace; if it absolutely must exist then it should be in `~/.local` somewhere and not on my desktop. What is this thing and how do I get rid of it?

Outputs of commands as follows:

```
$ ls -l ~/Desktop/chrome-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 inigo inigo 324 Oct 21 19:51 /home/inigo/Desktop/chrome-kljciollpkjgcpehbgbmhdnadoffelnc-Default.desktop

$ file ~/Desktop/chrome-*
/home/inigo/Desktop/chrome-kljciollpkjgcpehbgbmhdnadoffelnc-Default.desktop: a /usr/bin/env xdg-open script, ASCII text executable
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the file? For example, please add the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop/chrome-*`, and `file ~/Desktop/chrome-*` to your question.

Comment: Sure-- see edit. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks. So it's a desktop shortcut, a launcher. I am guessing chrome must have an option somewhere to "add launcher to desktop" or something. Is this Google Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: Can you also show us the contents of the file (`cat ~/Desktop/chrome-* `)?